# Phd field of expertise

Tags: soft-question

I'm not seeking personal advice but a field (to do a Phd in) in which you work with the following:

(1) Probability Theory in general and specifically stochastic processes (2) Measure Theory (3)  Functional Analysis (4) Numerics (5) Topology (6) No physics (7) No PDE theory

So I heard that in Mathematical Statistics you can use many of the fields ((1)-(6)) above. Could anybody working in Mathematical Statistics maybe say a few words about this field? How about Financial Math or Mathematical Biology. Do you know any fields which combine the above ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

According to my limited experience in biomedical research, researches concerning the human brain should have a good prospect in the coming decade. You may have a look at the following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Brain_Project
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRAIN_Initiative
https://www.technologyreview.com/s/526501/brain-mapping/

Note that huge amount of money is / will be invested into this field. The study of human brain also involve a lot of mathematics, as I heard in some conferences. You can explore more yourself if interested.

Comment: Oh yes, regarding your last question, (since I am doing my post-doc now, so as some of my friends), I can say usually the possibility to do a Post-doc in a related field of your PhD research is possible, particularly if your PhD research involves some mathematical theories that are applicable to other problems. 

For example, my PhD research used Granger casuality to analyze time series in gene regulatory network discovery [1,2], which was a hot research topic some years ago. The notion of Granger casuality can now be used to study brain functioning (e.g. see [3]).

Comment: [1] http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/12/i110.full

[2] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24067420

[3] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3868251/

Comment: Thanks for the info! And also especially for answering my second question. This already helps me a lot. However I Hope I still get some more concrete advise concerning my first question.